# Blow-up along a subscheme and along its associated reduced closed subscheme

Tags: blow-ups, ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme and let $Y$ be a closed subscheme of $X$. 
What relation is there between $\mathrm{Bl} _ {Y}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Bl} _{ Y _{\mathrm{red}}}(X)$ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no map from one blow up to the other, and definitely not an isomorphism.  Please see my comments to J.C. Ottems answer.

*However*, if you replace radical by integral closure, then everything is fine.

Here's what I mean, if $I$ is an ideal and $J$ is its integral closure, then you always have an everywhere defined map

$$Bl_J X \to Bl_I X.$$

This need not be an isomorphism, indeed the integral closure of $(x^2, y^2)$ is $(x^2, xy, y^2)$.  The blow up of the latter ideal is the normalization of the blow up of the former.

The other way you can get a map is if $J = \sqrt I$, and *also* if we can write $I = J \cdot \mathfrak{a}$ for some other ideal $\mathfrak{a}$.  Then the blow up of $I$ is always the blow up of $\mathfrak{a}$ pulled back to $Bl_J X$.

In general, you should expect no relation between the blow up of two ideals with the same radical unless there is some integral closure relation between them and/or one ideal is the product of the other (and something else).

Comment: In fact, this characterises all cases, according to http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1258138260.

Answer (score 10):

In general they can be very different. For example take the subscheme $Y$ of  $\mathbb{A}^2$ given by the ideal $(x^2,y)$. Here the blow up is covered by the two open subsets

$$U = \mbox{Spec} k[x, y][t]/(y − x^2t),\qquad V = \mbox{Spec} k[x, y][s]/(ys − x^2)$$

In particular the blow up of $Y$ is singular, whereas the blow-up of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at a point is not.

In general, even if you assume that both blow-ups are smooth, all sorts of things can happen depending on how complicated the ideal sheaf is. For example the blow-ups can have a different number of exceptional divisors and not even be related by a finite map. Even worse, *every birational morphism $X'\to X$ is the blow-up of $X$ along some ideal sheaf*.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But at least, there is a natural map from one to another?

Comment: I believe there is no map from one to the other. In the example J.C. Ottem gives, the blow up of $(x^2,y)$ can be obtained as follows. Blow up $(x,y)$, then blow up another point on that first blowup (the origin on one of the usual charts), and then contract the first exceptional curve. There's no map between $Bl_{(x^2,y)}X$ and $Bl_(x,y) X$, at least no map over $X$.$$\text{ }$$ Just because you have an inclusion of Rees algebras, does not mean that there is an everywhere defined map of the blow-ups. In the given example, one of the points of the overring contracts to an irrelevant ideal.